# How do I upgrade python-scipy to something newer than 0.7.0?

Tags: 10.04, package-management, partial-upgrade

How can I upgrade to a higher scipy (say 0.8.0) with a minimum amount of dependency hell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dug around a bit (quite a bit actually). 
Initially I tried installing enthoughts python ([EPD 7.0](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php)) it all looks nice and self-contained. Oddly enough though, one of the things I needed to run ([spyder](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/), check it out, brilliant IDE if your playing around with python in the natural sciences) would segfault. I wasn't able to find the problem (yet) so I had to move on.

Then I tried what I should have done in the first place, namely choosing newer debian packages - turns out the dependencies aren't as frightening as I thought:
installed natty's [numpy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/python-numpy) and [scipy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/python-scipy) and so far, all seems to work.

```
sudo dpkg -i python-numpy_1.5.1-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i python-scipy_0.8.0+dfsg1-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

with the result that

```
$ python -c 'import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)'
0.8.0
```

Comment: Good to know --  thanks for posting the complete solution.

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran python-pip
```

then

```
sudo pip install scipy
```

or, if you already have another version of scipy installed

```
sudo pip install --upgrade scipy
```

Answer (score 1):

As found [HERE](http://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/2011/11/09/install-numpy-and-scipy-on-ubuntu/):

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install scipy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  sudo easy_install scipy
```

or             `sudo easy_install3 scipy`

You may need to install `python-setuptools` or 
`python3-setuptools` first.

Comment: mh, but that only gets me what I have already: Searching for scipy Best match: scipy 0.7.0 Adding scipy 0.7.0 to easy-install.pth file

Comment: and if I force an upgrade: (sudo easy_install -U --dry-run scipy) I get a ValueError since the numpy requirement (>=1.4) is not satisfied (currently 1.3.0)

Comment: Sorry about that -- my system is happy with 0.9.0:
`Best match: scipy 0.9.0`
`Downloading ... md5=a37933c9e3c4fdf8d087624cd7dcb47d`
We seem to have different versions for dependencies....

Comment: So you're on 10.04 but have more recent versions of scipy (and likely some other packages as well)? How did you get there - probably not through apt-getting them, did you?

Comment: I've built a few things from git/svn etc., unfortunately.  I don't have a fresh install at the moment, but I'll see if I can reproduce when I get a chance.